# How to show that $\prod _{m\ge 1} \frac{1+\exp(i2\pi \cdot3^{-m})}{2}$ is non-zero?

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, analysis

I tried to take the $Log$ of $\prod _{m\ge 1} \frac{1+\exp(i2\pi \cdot3^{-m})}{2} = \prod _{m\ge 1} Z_m$, which gives

$$Log \prod_{m\ge 1} Z_m = \sum_{m \ge 1} Log (Z_m) = \sum_{m \ge 1} \ln |Z_m| + i \sum_{m \ge 1} \Theta_m,$$

where $\Theta_m$ is the principal argument of $Z_m$.

$|Z_m| = \left[\frac{1}{2} \left(1 + \cos(\frac{2\pi}{3^m}\right)\right]^{1/2}$ 
has the range $[0,1]$, so $\ln |Z_m| \le 0$. And, since there are infinitely many $m$'s sucu that $\ln|Z_m| \not = 0$, $\sum_{m \ge 1} \ln |Z_m| \to -\infty$.

Then, $$\exp\left({Log \prod_{m\ge 1} Z_m}\right) = \exp\left(\sum_{m \ge 1} \ln |Z_m| \right)\exp\left(i \sum_{m \ge 1} \Theta_m\right) = 0.$$

I want to show that $\prod _{m\ge 1} \frac{1+\exp(i2\pi \cdot3^{-m})}{2} $ is non-zero. What is wrong in the above reasonings?

Comment: You wrote "since there are infinitely many $m$'s sucu that $\ln|Z_m| \not = 0$, $\sum_{m \ge 1} \ln |Z_m| \to -\infty$". However, for example, note $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{2^i}\right) = -1$ which is not negative infinity.

Comment: are you sure the result is correct? For some reason, I am getting that the result is purely imaginary (and non zero)

Comment: @Conrad It's probably not, but I wanted to mean that the product is non-zero. Could you write an answer to show how you get the purely imaginary result?

Answer (score 1):

We can show the product $P$ above is purely imaginary and non zero as folows:

$\frac{1+\exp(i2\pi \cdot3^{-m})}{2}=1+a_m$, then $2|a_m|=|\exp(i2\pi \cdot3^{-m})-1|=O(2\pi \cdot3^{-m})$,

since $|\exp z-1|\le \exp |z|-1 \le 2|z|, |z| \le \frac{1}{2}$ and $2\pi \cdot3^{-m} \le \frac{1}{2}, m \ge 3$.

It then follows that $\sum {|a_m|}$ is finite, so the product $P=\prod _{m\ge 1}{(1+a_m)}$ converges to a finite non-zero ($a_m\ne -1$) value by general product theory (see below).

$\arg{\frac{1+\exp(ix)}{2}}=\frac{x}{2}, -\pi < x \le \pi$ so $\arg{\frac{1+\exp(i2\pi \cdot3^{-m})}{2}}=\pi \cdot3^{-m}$, so $\arg P=\sum_{m \ge 1}\pi \cdot3^{-m}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, so $P$ is purely imaginary

**Edit later:** since it seems to be a question encountered often let's show that if we have a complex product $P=\prod _{m\ge 1}{(1+a_m)}$, and if $\sum|{a_m}| < \infty$ and all $a_m \ne -1$ then $P$ converges to a finite non zero value.

Proof: by excluding finitely many terms we can assume $|a_m| \le \frac{1}{2}$ and since $a_m \ne -1$ the excluded finite product is non-zero, so it is enough to prove the result under the assumption $|a_m| \le \frac{1}{2}$ since $P=P_{finite}Q, P_{finite} \ne 0$, $Q$ infinite product satisfying the latter assumption.

Note now that if $|z| \le \frac{1}{2}$, $|\log(1+z)| \le |z|+\frac{|z|^2}{2}+..\frac{|z|^k}{k}+...=|\log(1-|z|)| \le 2|z|$ since $2x-|\log(1-x)|=2x+\log(1-x)$ is increasing on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and it is zero at zero!

But then we can take the principal logarithm so if $P_n$ is the product of the first $n$ terms, $\log P_n = \sum_{m\le n} \log (1+a_m)$, so $|\log P_n - \log P_k|\le \sum_{k+1 \le m \le n} |\log(1+a_m)| \le 2\sum_{k+1 \le m \le n}{|a_m|} \to 0, n \ge k \to \infty$ so $\log{P_n}$ hence $P_n$ is Cauchy and obviously $|\log P_n| \le A$ means $\Re{\log P_n} \ge -\sqrt {A}, |P_n| \ge e^{-\sqrt {A}}$ hence $|P| \ge e^{-\sqrt {A}} >0$

Answer (score 1):

Write the $m^{\text{th}}$ term as: 
$$\frac{1+\exp\left(2\pi i/3^m\right)}{2} = \frac{1+\cos\left(2\pi/3^m\right)}{2} + i\frac{\sin\left(2\pi/3^m\right)}{2}.$$
The first term is $\cos^{2}\left(\pi/3^m\right)$, and the second one is $i\cos\left(\pi/3^m\right)\sin\left(\pi/3^m\right)$. There's a common factor of $\cos\left(\pi/3^m\right)$ which tends to $1$, so that product probably doesn't tend to zero.

The other factor is 
$$\cos (\cdot) + i\sin (\cdot) = \exp\left(i\pi/3^m\right).$$

that infinite product is not hard, it's $\exp(i\pi/2)$, or simply $i$.

Comment: This looks promising, but why $\prod_{ m \ge 1} cos(\pi/3^m) \not = 0$?

Comment: It's not totally clear to me either yet, I just don't expect it to. For intuition, $\cos(\pi/3^{m}) = 1 - O(3^{-2m})$, so you'd expect $\Pi^{N} \cos(\pi/3^{m}) = 1 - \sum^{N} O(3^{-2m}) = 1 - O(1)$ (I was expecting this to be closer to $1$ than it is, I'll keep thinking)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3460526/426645 I also posted a question about this.